# Generate all possible combinations from a string array without repetition

Tags: java

I want to compare each element of string array with the other elements except itself, the result will be a character string separated by this `-->`, the 2nd part of result will be the element and the 1st part will be 1 or more character strings separated by `,`

for exemple vect[a1,a2,a3]
Out put:

```
a2-->a1
a3-->a1
a2,a3 -->a1

a1-->a2
a3-->a2
a1,a3 -->a2

a1-->a3
a2-->a3
a1,a2-->a3
```

i try this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String vect[] = { "a1", "a2", "a3" };
        int n = 3;
        String attribut;

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            attribut = vect[i];
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (!attribut.equals(vect[j])) {
                    System.out.println(vect[j] + "-->" + attribut);

                }
            }
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                    if ((!attribut.equals(vect[j])) && (!attribut.equals(vect[k]))) {
                        System.out.println(vect[j] + "," + vect[k] + "-->" + attribut);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

the code returns the result but I don't know how to do when i have an array with for example 5 strings of characters 
for exemple  vect[a1,a2,a3,a4]
out put

```
a2-->a1
a3-->a1
a4-->a1
a2,a3 -->a1
a2,a4 -->a1
a3,a4-->a1
a2,a3,a4 -->a1
....
```

in this case the number of commas before the --> increases to 4.

Comment: Wrong string comparison, watch out.

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica I have corrected thank you for your remark but I can't find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bit-manipulation, we can easily iterate over all combinations of strings from an array of strings.

For example, if we have 3 strings (`"a1"`, `"a2"`, `"a3"`), we will iterate from 1 to 7 (2³-1). In the binary representation of those number, each bit, from the right, specifies whether that input string is included in the result.

```
001    "a1"
010    "a2"
011    "a1", "a2"
100    "a3"
101    "a1", "a3"
110    "a2", "a3"
111    "a1", "a2", "a3"
```

Now we modify that logic to pull out the string value that goes on the right of the `-->`. Let's call that the *result* value.

For example, if we're current generating the result for `"a2"` (result index 1), we "pull" that out of the bit pool, so we now only have 2 bit. Any bit on or after the result index represents a value index one higher than the bit index.

That means that bit 0 is value index 0, but bit 1 is value index 2.

```
01    "a1"
10    "a3"
11    "a1", "a3"
```

We can now write code to do is this way:

```java
static void printCombinations(String... values) {
    if (values.length < 2 || values.length > 30)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There must be between 2 and 30 values (got " + values.length + ")");
    if (values.length != new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values)).size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate values not allowed");

    final int maxBit = values.length - 1;
    final int maxMask = 1 << maxBit;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int resIdx = 0; resIdx < values.length; resIdx++) {
        for (int bitMask = 1; bitMask < maxMask; bitMask++) {
            buf.setLength(0);
            for (int bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < maxBit; bitIdx++)
                if ((bitMask & (1 << bitIdx)) != 0)
                    buf.append(',').append(values[bitIdx >= resIdx ? bitIdx + 1 : bitIdx]);
            System.out.println(buf.append("-->").append(values[resIdx]).substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
printCombinations("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4");
```

*Output*

```
a2-->a1
a3-->a1
a2,a3-->a1
a4-->a1
a2,a4-->a1
a3,a4-->a1
a2,a3,a4-->a1
a1-->a2
a3-->a2
a1,a3-->a2
a4-->a2
a1,a4-->a2
a3,a4-->a2
a1,a3,a4-->a2
a1-->a3
a2-->a3
a1,a2-->a3
a4-->a3
a1,a4-->a3
a2,a4-->a3
a1,a2,a4-->a3
a1-->a4
a2-->a4
a1,a2-->a4
a3-->a4
a1,a3-->a4
a2,a3-->a4
a1,a2,a3-->a4
```

Comment: Thanks the code is functional but I didn't understand why you have values.length > 30 and can you explain to me the loop where bitIdx

Comment: @Cissus The code is using an `int` for the `bitMask`, so there are 32 bits. To prevent overflow into negative numbers, Limiting to 30 bits is needed, though it can use 31 bits with a little extra logic. 30 bits support 31 `values`, but I like the round number 30 as the upper limit. That would still generate more the half a *billion* combinations, so that's hardly much of a constraining limit anyway. --- The `bitIdx` loop is for iterating through the bits of the `bitMask`, and collecting the `values` related to each 1-bit.

Comment: I still don't understand what you've done :( 
I know that resIdx is the index to the right side of ` -->`
but why bitMask < maxMask please I want more details I'm a beginner, comment me the code or give me another example like the one from a2 so that I can understand

Comment: @Cissus Sounds like you don't know bit-manipulation, so start by researching that to learn more.